# JDOM exception Spring MVC

Tags: spring, exception, spring-mvc, jar, rome

I'm trying to create RSS feeds for my web site and I'm using the rome 1.0 library. When I run my project I get the following:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/JDOMException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:839)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

    root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jdom/JDOMException
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.feed.AbstractFeedView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractFeedView.java:62)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

    root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jdom.JDOMException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.feed.AbstractFeedView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractFeedView.java:62)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

I search on the internet and they said probably a library is missing.But i put the rome library in the direction:

```
   WEB-INF/lib
```

I'm trying to understand the root of the problem and i can't.Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, you're also missing [JDOM](http://jdom.org/).

Comment: Probably, you're getting a new exception?

Comment: The same one.I can't understand

Comment: One of the answers i found on my problem was: "It worked when I moved the jdom.jar file to the JBoss default server's lib directory". My problem is that i'm not using the JBoss server.I'm using the apache server